# What is the open square? (Genesis 19:2)

Tags: genesis

Genesis 19 NKJV records:

> Now the two angels came to Sodom in the evening, and Lot was
> sitting in the gate of Sodom. When Lot saw them, he rose to meet them,
> and he bowed himself with his face toward the ground. 2 And he said,
> “Here now, my lords, please turn in to your servant’s house and spend
> the night, and wash your feet; then you may rise early and go on your
> way.”
>
> And they said, “No, but **we will spend the night in the open
> square.**”
>
> 3 But he insisted strongly; so they turned in to him and entered his
> house. Then he made them a feast, and baked unleavened bread, and they
> ate.

- What does it mean to spend the night in the *open square*?
- What did this entail? Would this be outside without cover (in the open)?

Answer (score 2):

The term [rechob](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/7339.htm) is related to the concept of openness and is translated as  town square, open square, public space, or even "the streets."  What is clear from the context is that it is the opposite of "indoors."

The OP asks if this means the angels would spend the night outside without cover. The answer is "not necessarily." A town plaza (or "the streets") might be located in an area with overhanging porticoes. A lean-to against bordering structures is another possibility. In a town square, unremoved tables and booths used for marketing could also provide some shelter. Finally, travelers would often carry material to form a rudimentary tent in which they could protect themselves from the elements.

**Conclusion**: The "open square" was most likely a place where townsfolk congregated for marketing and festivals. The text does not make it clear whether any shelters were located there.

Answer (score 0):

Genesis 19:1-3 says the two angels initially turned down Lot’s offer to give them shelter for the night in his own home.  Lot knew just how dangerous the inhabitants of the city were.  The KJV says:

> “we will abide in the street all night”

The NIV says:

> “we will spend the night in the square”

2 Chronicles 32:6 speaks of a large square in Jerusalem, an outdoor area, at the city gate, where public gatherings were held.  This is when Hezekiah took steps to prevent Sennacherib from taking the city by force:

> He appointed military officers over the people and assembled them before him in the square at the city gate...

The two angels were prepared to spend all night outside in the square/street, but Lot dissuaded them.

P.S. Hebrews 13:2 reminds us, “Do not forget to show hospitality to strangers, for by so doing some people have shown hospitality to angels without knowing it.”

P.P.S. I had framed my answer on Tuesday morning but problems with my laptop meant I could not post it till Wednesday morning. I up-voted Dan's answer, for what that's worth.